# Backflow from Bathtub

Tags: plumbing

Over the past few months, I've noticed occasional "gurgling" within my bathtub drain. Over the past week, I've had 2 occasions where there has been significant backflow from the drain into the tub. Along with the water, there is what looks like dust and other types of debris. I'm considering a call to a local plumber in order to have the drain snaked, but I'm wondering what may be causing this. I live on the first floor of a 3 floor condominium complex and I'm wondering whether this is something that I may have caused, or whether this could be a building-wide issue, and therefore a matter for the HOA. In other words, is it likely that a plumber can resolve this issue by snaking my drain, or might this require something more involved? Thanks for your help.[image: Backflow]

Comment: I should note that the water eventually went back down the drain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a clog. If it backs up rather quickly you might assume it is a "local" issue, meaning your responsibility. If it takes a while then it's probably farther on down the line, and perhaps a communal responsibility.

Talk to your neighbors and see if anyone else is having any problems.